# Modularization of dymaic allocation of a matrix in C

Tags: c, dynamic, allocation

I tried to allocate a matrix in **int main** and I have checked the code and after that I wanted to create specific functions for allocation, reading and printing the matrix and I got some errors I didn't know how to correct.

Below is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int *aloc_array(int n) 
{
  int *v =(int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int *));
  if(v = NULL){
    free(v);
    return NULL;
  }
  return v;
}

int **aloc_matrix(int n, int *v)
{
    int **mat = (int **)malloc(n* sizeof(int *));
    if (mat = NULL){
        free(mat);
        return NULL;
    }
    for (int i =0 ; i < n; i++){    
        if (mat[i] == NULL) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            free(mat[j]);
        }
        free(mat);
        return NULL;
    }

        scanf("%d", &v[i]);

        mat[i] = (int *)malloc(v[i]* sizeof(int));
        for (int j = 0; j < v[i]; j++)
            scanf("%X", &mat[i][j]);
    } 
    return mat;
}
 void print_matrix(int n, int *v, int **mat)
 {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        for ( int j = 0; j < v[i]; j++){
            printf("%08X", mat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
 }



int main(void){
    int n, *v, **mat;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    v = aloc_array(n);
    mat =aloc_matrix(n, *v);
    print_matrix(n, *v, *mat);

    return 0;
}
```

This is an example of error I get.

000.c:56:25: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘print_matric’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

Answer (score 0):

You should just pass the variables, dont dereference them

```
print_matrix(n, v, mat);
```

note , this is wrong

```
 int *v =(int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int *));
```

should be

```
 int *v =(int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few bugs in your code:

1. In the following 2 lines you are assigning, not comparing:

   ```
   if(v = NULL) 
   if (mat = NULL)
   ```

And lets suppose the result of the comparison was TRUE, the value was NULL... you don't have to call free on it!

2. The following line:

   ```
   int *v =(int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int *));
   ```

Although it might work, should be changed to:

```
  int *v =(int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

3. You don't need to put the * in the last 2 function calls, change them to:

   ```
   mat =aloc_matrix(n, v);
   print_matrix(n, v, mat);
   ```